# How to use regex instead of set to convert exception words to lower case?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, set

This is what I have done so far. I am capitalizing the first alphabet of all the words except 'by','and', 'of', 'it', 'the', 'at' etc., (the list is goes on).

Expected output: Dance by Cow

Output I received was : Dance by Cow

But now I want to use regex for this, instead of Set. (reduces space complexity).

Also I wanted to know how to split in a scenario where there is '-' & '_' in an array of words?

```
let titleCase = str => {
    const exceptions = new Set(['by', 'and']); // handling the specific words
    if (typeof str == 'number') {
      str = JSON.stringify(str);
    }
    return str
      .toLowerCase()
      .split('-')
      .map(s =>
        exceptions.has(s) ? s : s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1)
      )
      .join(' ');
  };

toTitleCase('dance-by-cow');
```

Comment: Handling an explicit set of exception words is not best done with RegEx. For just the two words "and" and "by", it's easy enough, but it will get messy the more exception words you add. (And if your only exceptions will always just be those two, then your space complexity is tiny and there's no need to change it.)

Comment: Wait, if that's all your exceptions, then...the space complexity for using a Set is `O(1)`. It doesn't change with the input, hence it's a constant.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk what is there is more exceptions. In that case I want to know how to handle it with RegEx.

Comment: @VLAZ I didn't articulate it properly, my bad. There will be more exceptions and I want to know know how to handle it via RegEx.

Comment: But if the exceptions *never change* based on the input, you have a constant space complexity - `O(1)`. That's what constant means. It is also not terribly useful to judge what the actual space requirement would be. You can easily have an algorithm that just over-provisions and grabs 1 gigabyte of memory every time it runs, even if it doesn't need always it. That's *constant* but worse than allocating memory proportional to the input (which is `O(n)`), assuming the input is much less than 1GB

Comment: @Jeena OK, so if there's more exceptions, like I said, it'll be messier to do with RegExp. The only way would be to hardcode all the exceptions into your RegExp string, which by the way would take up at least the same amount of space as hardcoding them into a Set, but it would be harder to read and write. Your Set approach is probably the best way to do this.